# How can I make a PostgreSQL query faster so that it gives back the lowest values?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by, min

I have the following data:

| id1 | id2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 281 | 33453 | 23 |
| 281 | 33452 | 23 |
| 281 | 36466 | 24 |
| 282 | 12118 | 14 |
| 282 | 27603 | 18 |

How do I write my query in PostgreSQL in the most efficient way so that I keep all id2 values belonging to id1 where the score is the lowest (for every id1)? Or in other words, I want to have following result:

| id1 | id2 | min_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 281 | 33453 | 23 |
| 281 | 33452 | 23 |
| 282 | 12118 | 14 |

I'm using following query so far:

```sql
‌‌SELECT m1.id1, m1.id2, m2.min_score 
FROM test m1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id1, MIN(score) as min_score
      FROM test
      GROUP BY id1
      ) m2
ON (m1.id1 = m2.id1 AND m1.score = m2.min_score) 
ORDER BY m1.id1, m2.min_score
```

Is there a faster way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! You're right, I will adapt my question because I indeed wanted to have the ORDER BY in my overall query.

Comment: You say you want the lowest score for each id1/id2 _combination_. However there are no duplicate combinations of id1/id2 so the input data would essentially be the output data. Your query shows the all rows with the minimum value per `id1` - not per combination.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my question is not correct (my native language is not English sorry). I will adapt my question, what I want to have is all id2 values belonging to id1 where the score is the lowest

Comment: I think that your query is fine except probably that `order by` part is to be touched as `m2.min_score` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this with a window function rather than a join:

```
select id1, id2, score as min_score from (
    select *, rank() over (partition by id1 order by score) as rank 
    from test
) foo 
where rank=1
ORDER BY id1, min_score;
```

As for which method will be faster, try it and see.  If you want help interpreting the results, show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of it done each way.  You should probably choose between them based on how easy it is for you to understand them, not based on speed.  Some people intuitively grasp window functions, and some people don't.

Comment: I tested this query and it's remarkably faster than mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question again I will edit it to the alt method to do it. Depending on how your database runs it operations this might be slightly faster or slower.

```
SELECT distinct a.id1, a.id2, a.minscore
FROM test a,
(SELECT id1, min(score) as minscore
FROM test
group by id1
) AS b
WHERE a.id= b.id
```

might return results faster
edit log: fixed typo

Comment: oh i forgot a comma does 
select id1, id2, min(score) as min_score
from test m1
group by id1, id2
order by id1;

work?

Comment: I changed my question! See comments from @a_horse_with_no_name. So not the answer I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: You changed your question, but not the desired result. Looks like your sample data do not make the difference clear. I think you should improve that.

Comment: Oh I just understand what you mean now, let me adapt the code real quick

Comment: so I loaded the alt method for how to do it that performs faster sometimes, but I honestly thing your speed should be really ok already